# Linux Sed won't work on large files (3GB)

Tags: linux, sed

I have a large file (>3GB) which has a single line containing content similar to below

{"id","1","name":"one"},{"id","2","name":"two"},{"id","3","name":"three"},

I am using sed to search and replace }, with },\n so that each dictionary is on its own line.

```
sed 's/},/},\\n/g' FILE >> NEW_FILE
```

This doesn't work all the time and I had to split the file into smaller 1GB chunks, replace the text on each smaller file then combine it.

Is there any other way to do the search and replace on this large file.

Comment: How much memory do you have? If your file contains a single line, it will read it into memory and do the processing there (sed works line-based). so if you have 3GB of data pushed in a single line, this could be problematic for your system. [GNU sed’s Limitations and Non-limitations](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html)

Comment: Its a server with 64GB of mem. And although it runs several processes almost always it should have at least 20GB mem free

Comment: try `awk -v RS='},' '{print $0 RT}'`

Comment: Install GNU sed if you don't have it already

Comment: Is the file a JSON? There are tools that can process JSON, even a streamed one.

Comment: Yes its a json, I will see if there are other ways to process it.